# If I improve an edit suggestion, does the suggester still get +2 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

I just got a [good suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/157), but I wanted to tweak the title some more. If I choose to improve this edit, will Diago still get his +2 reputation bonus?

Comment: Heh, Grace FGITWed me here :)

Comment: @badp She does that. *glares*

Comment: Aaargh Diago, don't change "dependent" to "dependant"!

Comment: @mmyers Say, is the difference there covered in English Language & Usage yet? Because I had thought it was correct, which is why I approved it rather than improved it.

Comment: @Grace Note: I think "dependant" might be a British usage. Let me look up the question. Edit: [Here you go](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/dependent-or-dependant-on-or-to-or-from).

Comment: @mmyers Thank you much! Looks like I double-botched on this one, eheh.

Comment: @Michael Oh, I'm not annoyed. I learned to love it.

Comment: Interesting question, thanks for asking it. @GraceNote: Here in Britain, we consider our children dependants because they are dependent on us. The term in the question should be "level-dependent" in British usage too, because it's an adjectival phrase. Anyhoo...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes; it shows up as back to back edits in the revision history, and the original suggester gets the rep for their edit, even though yours immediately modifies it

Comment: confirmed, but ... open to discussion / change, if I see the majority of edits through improve are **bodge** I will have to remove the bonus