# Can I earn 2 reputation when my suggest edit is improved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I improve an edit suggestion, does the suggester still get +2 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80524/if-i-improve-an-edit-suggestion-does-the-suggester-still-get-2-rep)

When my suggest edit is improved, It will saved as an old version, and that means my edit is approved.

But I also have a question: Can I earn 2 reputation when my suggest edit is improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if someone clicks the `improve` button, your edit is considered to be approved by Community ♦, so you do receive the 2 point rep bonus.

The editor who improved it will be listed as the most current editor, however.